# Disable Quick Access Folder Options using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry, explorer, windows-explorer

I would like to put together a PowerShell script that will uncheck the following Folder Options (Folder Options > General > Privacy):
**"Show recently used files in Quick access"** & **"Show frequently used folders in Quick access"**

[image: Disable Quick Access Folder Options]

I tried to find the registry locations for these two options so I could disable them that way, but I had no luck identifying the location that needed to be updated. I was reviewing this registry location: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the script I used to turn off those two settings:

```
#Uncheck "Show recently used files in Quick access" & Uncheck "Show frequently used folders in Quick Access" for OS account currently logged in
$FolderOptionsPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $FolderOptionsPath -Name ShowFrequent -Value '0'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $FolderOptionsPath -Name ShowRecent -Value '0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*depending on all users or single user, follow proper tree*
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

Value: `ShowRecent` & `ShowFrequent`

Data: 1 or 0